# Using decorator function, rest parameters, call and apply

Tags: javascript

```js
let worker = {
  slow(min, max) {
    alert(`Called with ${min},${max}`);
    return min + max;
  }
};

function cachingDecorator(func, hash) {
  let cache = new Map();
  return function() {
    let key = hash(arguments); //...arguments also works, but only with this name, another no, why?
    if (cache.has(key)) {
      return cache.get(key);
    }

    let result = func.call(this, ...arguments); 

    cache.set(key, result);
    return result;
  };
}

function hash(args) {
  return args[0] + ',' + args[1];
}

worker.slow = cachingDecorator(worker.slow, hash);
   alert( worker.slow(3, 5) ); // works
   alert( "Again " + worker.slow(3, 5) ); // same (cached)
```

It's about using decorator function. First call is calculated, and then it's cashed and is taken from cash.
I've read, that arguments object it's old way to use rest parameter, and it can be replaced. Then why when I try to replace arguments object in `let key = hash(arguments)`

```
return function() {
    let key = hash(arguments); 
    if (cache.has(key)) {
    return cache.get(key);
}
```

to rest parameter, it doesn't work...

Actually it works, but only if add `...(...arguments)`, but it doesn't if 
change on smth else(I mean arguments), e.g `arr`, `ars` etc. Why?

Comment: Post the actual code that's failing, it's hard to tell what you're trying to change to.

Comment: @Barmar I've added comment on the line 10

Comment: `arguments` is a special built-in keyword that automatically gets all the arguments to the function. It's similar to defining the function as `function(...arguments)`

Comment: You still haven't shown the version that doesn't work. What are you replacing `arguments` with?

Comment: You could do `function(...myargs)` and then you would use `hash(myargs)`

Comment: @Barmar It's the point))) it doesn't work if replace name.

Comment: Yes it does. Please **show** what you tried in code, instead of describing it in words.

Answer (score 0):

For all non-arrow function there is a local variable `arguments` see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Without `arguments` you can get the values by using rest parameters

```
return function(...myArgs) {
    let key = hash(myArgs)
    ...
```

Or, if you are passing arguments to hash function after destructuring like

```
let key = hash(...arguments)
```

change your hash function as

```
function hash(hMin, hMax) {
  return hMin + ',' + hMax;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 'arguments object it's old way to use rest parameter, and it can be
>   replaced'

Actually, they are different.
Any function declared with keyword 'function' has an object 'arguments' which can be used inside of function. Even if you have use rest operator inside, it still available as well as your 'rest' array.

```
function foo (...args) {
console.log(args) // returns an array when foo below is called [1,23,5]
console.log(arguments) // returns an object when foo below is called {"0":1,"1":23,"2":5}
}

foo(1,23,5)
```

The 'arguments' object is not available when arrow function is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own name instead of the built-in `arguments`, by using `...` in the function definition and the call.

```js
let worker = {
  slow(min, max) {
    alert(`Called with ${min},${max}`);
    return min + max;
  }
};

function cachingDecorator(func, hash) {
  let cache = new Map();
  return function(...myArgs) {
    let key = hash(myArgs);
    if (cache.has(key)) {
      return cache.get(key);
    }

    let result = func.call(this, ...myArgs);

    cache.set(key, result);
    return result;
  };
}

function hash(args) {
  return args[0] + ',' + args[1];
}

worker.slow = cachingDecorator(worker.slow, hash);
alert(worker.slow(3, 5)); // works
alert("Again " + worker.slow(3, 5)); // same (cached)
```

Comment: Thanks!) I should've listened to you when you told me post code that doesn't work. Because now  I see why my version didn't worked... I've been changing . . . in `hash(myArgs)` and you added it as parameter to `return function(...myArgs) `. But why so? Why we should add it this way?

Comment: How else would it know that `myArgs` should be the function's arguments?